# How do I check many values inside script in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I can easily show/hide a `<div>` based on this View code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.countryID, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.countryID, ((IEnumerable<Corporate.Models.Country>) ViewBag.Possiblecountries).OrderBy(c =>  c.countryName).Select(option => new SelectListItem
    {
       Text = Html.DisplayTextFor(_ => option.countryName).ToString(),
       Value = option.countryID.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
       Selected = (Model != null) && (option.countryID == Model.countryID)
    }), new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.countryID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="vatNumberDiv">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.vatNumber, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.vatNumber, new {@class = "form-control"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.vatNumber, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    </div>
</div>
```

and based on this Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#countryID').change(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value == 'FRA') {
            $('#vatNumberDiv').show();                
        } else {
            $('#vatNumberDiv').hide();               
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

but what about checking all the EU members? I have a method called `bool IsMemberEU()` that requires MVC context to execute. Can I call it inside the script?

Maybe it's better to generate by code all the options inside the script? Something like:

```
if (value == 'FRA' ||
    value == 'DEU' ||
    value == 'ITA' ||
    ...
    ...
   ) {
```

Do I have some other option?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

This is the code I need, to check if the country is EU member:

```
foreach(Country c in context.Countries)
{
   if (IsMemberEU(c))
   {
      // is EU memeber
   }
}
```

**EDIT2:** For *M12 Bennet*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// $(function () {
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#countryID').change(function () {

        // get selected option to submit to method IsMemberEU
        var selectedOption = $(this).val();

        // create URL for ajax call
        var ajaxUrl = '@Url.Action("IsMemberEU", "Customers")';

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxUrl,
            data: { countryAbbv: selectedOption },
            success: function(result) {

                if (result) {
                    $("#vatNumberDiv").show();

                } else {
                    $("#vatNumberDiv").hide();

                }

                // show result of ajax call in the `p` element on page.  This is just testing to see if ajax call worked.
                // this can be done with console.log(result) as well.
                $("#ShowResult").text(result);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(xhr);
            }


        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You have to make an ajax call on your IsMemberEU() method to get JSON response in true or false. However, you can create a razor extension method as well.

Comment: Why don' you make an ajax call and check if the country is in EU.

Comment: @Gagan: Is the Ajax call compatible with the code I've added in the EDIT section?

Comment: ofcourse. in javascript code you have your country code, send the country via Jquery ajax call to your `IsMemberEU()` method and get the returned value in your success function of ajax call.

Comment: No, in javascript I have only a string like `"FRA"`, not the `Country` object.

Comment: @abenci what are all of the strings you possess and use in your javascript for European countries?  I would say that this is a static solution, meaning that if anything were needed to be changed, you would have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a controller, you could create the method `IsMemberEU(string countryAbbv)`.  It needs to accept a parameter because you're checking against what you're sending to the method.  So your code could look like this:

**Controller Method**

```
public bool IsMemberEU(string countryAbbv)
{
    var lstCountries = db.Countries.Where(x => x.isEU).Select(t => t.Abbr).ToList();

    return lstCountries.Contains(countryAbbv);
}
```

Then on your Razor/HTML page:

**Razor/HTML**

```
<div>
    <select id="CountrySelect" name="countryAbbv">
        <option value="">-- Select Country --</option>
        <option value="FRA">FRA</option>
        <option value="DEU">DEU</option>
        <option value="ITA">ITA</option>
        <option value="USA">USA</option>
    </select>

    <p id="ShowResult"></p>
</div>
```

Then in your jQuery to include AJAX:

**jQuery/AJAX**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // create event listener for change of select
        $("#CountrySelect").change(function() {

            // get selected option to submit to method IsMemberEU
            var selectedOption = $(this).val();

            // create URL for ajax call
            var ajaxUrl = '@Url.Action("IsMemberEU", "Home")';

            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxUrl,
                data: { countryAbbv: selectedOption },
                success: function(result) {
                    if (result)
                        $("#vatNumberDiv").show();
                    else
                        $("#vatNumberDiv").hide();
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log(xhr);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is working as expected on my end.  Now, this is just a basic example that I created myself based off of the information that was provided in the question. You shouldn't have to worry about the HTML/Razor that I provided because you're using Razor syntax.

Comment: These values are inside a MS SQL database table called `Countries` in the form `Abbr, Name,  isEU`, I need to pull the values using the EntityFramework. Please see the EDIT section in my question.

Comment: When you say "pull the values", do you mean create a list of `Abbr` in the controller method.  It seems as though you have a `bool` value in your database called `isEU` so why not just pull that?

Comment: I'm able to show True or False, thanks! One last step is missing: how do I check `result` to call `if (result) { $('#vatNumberDiv').show(); } else {                        $('#vatNumberDiv').hide(); }`? I've placed it after `success: function(result) {` but it does not work...

Comment: I've double checked and restarted the debugging section, I can see True or False swapping but not the `<div>` disappear... What else should I check?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code you're currently using?

Comment: Hi M12 Bennet, I've attached my code in the `EDIT2` section. I've double checked this morning, unluckily it does not work. Thanks.

Comment: Resolved! I had to change this: `if (result) {` to this `if (result === "True") {`. Thanks a lot.